# JQuery wide menu drop down with external div

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to create a 'drop down' menu that is 100% of the screen width but is triggered by a link in the header that is constrained with position:relative.  I have my header set with

elements like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="cell-logo"><a href="/">logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link01">link01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link02">link02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link03">link03</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

So if I click on Link01, I want a menu from another div to appear that looks like this:

```
<div class="menu-frame">
<section>
    <ul>
        <li><strong>header</strong></li>
        <li><a href="#">link01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link04</a></li>
    </ul><!-- ./  list -->
    <ul>
        <li><strong>header</strong></li>
        <li><a href="#">link01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link04</a></li>
    </ul><!-- ./  list -->
    <ul>
        <li><strong>header</strong></li>
        <li><a href="#">link01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link04</a></li>
    </ul><!-- ./ list -->
</section>
</div><!-- ./ menu-frame -->
```

The problem I run into is that should I use css to make that visible, I need to have it within the container of the nav tags and that constrains the width based on some nested position: relative; css.

If I use JS, I can get it to appear, but then the on state of the link goes away on mouseout and the menu disappears as well.

Below is my current css for the menu:

```
position: absolute;
top: 72px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height: 297px;
border-top: 5px solid #cccccc;
-moz-box-shadow:    0 5px 10px 0 #e8e8e8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #e8e8e8;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 #e8e8e8;
background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(247,247,247,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f7f7f7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
z-index: 100;
```

When I tried to use CSS, I had the left: 0 set to left: -99999, and when I tried JS, I had the display set to none.

I am open to any solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: In terms of your structure, I don't think the logo belongs in a list of links so I would separate that out from the nav completely. Also, I think semantically, each bit of drop-down content belongs with its associated element in your list of navigation links. I would therefore consider having the section as a child of each list element in the navigation

Comment: Also, you'd help people to help you if you set up a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The problem with associating the drop down with the nav element is that the drop down is meant to be 100% wide while the container it is in is confined by other layers that are set to position: relative.  So even if I set it to position: absolute, it would only span to the width of that container. So making each drop down a dhild of the list element would prevent me from being able to go 100%.  Would setting it to the window width with JQuery override the css?

Comment: Oh and thanks for the hint on jsfiddle.  I will see if I can set one up!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved this problem by using offset.left to set the distance between the element and the left side of the screen.  Then, the css left element is set to "-"+offset.left+"px".

Here is the JS Fiddle for it:

```
/* wide menu dropdown */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.nav1").hover(function () {
        var pos = $(this).offset();
        $(".menu-frame").width($(window).width());
        $(".menu-frame").css("left", "-" + pos.left + "px", "top", "40px")
        $("li.nav1 a.link01").addClass("highlight");
        $(".menu-frame").slideToggle(300, "linear");
    }, function () {
        $(".menu-frame").slideToggle(300, "linear");
        $("li.nav1 a.link01").removeClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6ubX/1/

The only things I would like to do from here is to make this JS more automated, rather than having to write it again for each nav instance, and to havea some sort of delay in triggering the closing of the div so that if I mouse out of the drop down super quick it doesn't disappear.  But those are probably for a different topic.

Thanks!